# getting cron specific pid

Tags: php, linux, cron, pid

I am working on a system where i would like to create and destroy cronjobs.
Now when i create the following cronjobs for example:

```
1****    /path/users.php?id=2
1****    /path/users.php?id=3
```

Then i would like to kill the first cronjob users.php?id=2
I am wondering if each cron creates a specific processid (PID) through unix and if so, how can i catch this specific processid?

I have tried the `echo $$` command however, i doubt that this command generates this specific Cron PID.

Comment: What i usually do is to dig into /proc filesystem, iterate through process directories and read a file in them, which contains the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly call the script with php and not via http you can place this in your php script:

```
file_put_contents("/absolute_path/cronjob_users_id_2.pid", getmypid());
```

This writes the PID of the process in a file.

If the script eventually comes to an end you can simply delete the file:

```
unlink($pidfile);
```

Comment: The solution was actually using the echo $$ command on the script i was executing at that moment (users.php). I read that the getmypid() function was not the correct function to kill that specific process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function remove($id)
    {
        $file = file(path/to/cron_file);
        $content = '';

        foreach( $file as $line )
        {
            list($url, $t_id) = explode('?id=', $line);

            if( trim($t_id) != $id )
            {
                $content .= $line;
            }
        }

        file_put_contents(path/to/cron_file, $content);
    }
```